# Why its so hard to get GATT specifications for hearing devices?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to find bluetooth GATT specifications for glucose meters and hearing devices.
But the only thing I've found is

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/removed/

or some older repositories on git hub.

I want to develop a simple volume control for hearing devices for example I can scan it here and find out:

```
Service: <CBService: 0x100606f20, isPrimary = NO, UUID = Device Information>
Service: <CBService: 0x1005747d0, isPrimary = NO, UUID = Battery>
Service: <CBService: 0x100574b90, isPrimary = NO, UUID = 7D74F4BD-C74A-4431-862C-CCE884371592>
Service: <CBService: 0x100574b30, isPrimary = NO, UUID = 8341F2B4-C013-4F04-8197-C4CDB42E26DC>
Service: <CBService: 0x100606fe0, isPrimary = NO, UUID = 14293049-77D7-4244-AE6A-D3873E4A3184>
Service: <CBService: 0x100607020, isPrimary = NO, UUID = 56772EAF-2153-4F74-ACF3-4368D99FBF5A>
Service: <CBService: 0x100607060, isPrimary = NO, UUID = 0A23AE62-C4C2-43D1-87B1-E8C83839A063>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10056f9f0, UUID = Manufacturer Name String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10056e6d0, UUID = Model Number String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10056e440, UUID = Hardware Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10056e4a0, UUID = Firmware Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100572130, UUID = Software Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100606120, UUID = Battery Level, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100708c60, UUID = 24E1DFF3-AE90-41BF-BFBD-2CF8DF42BF87, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100608100, UUID = 8D17AC2F-1D54-4742-A49A-EF4B20784EB3, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1006060b0, UUID = C97D21D3-D79D-4DF8-9230-BB33FA805F4E, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100608410, UUID = 497EEB9E-B194-4F35-BC82-36FD300482A6, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100608470, UUID = F3F594F9-E210-48F3-85E2-4B0CF235A9D3, properties = 0x1A, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has read
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10056e650, UUID = 6AC46200-24EA-46D8-A136-81133C65840A, properties = 0x1A, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has read
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100572190, UUID = 21FF4275-C41D-4486-A0E3-DC11138BCDE6, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100573fd0, UUID = A391C6F1-20BB-495A-ABBF-2017098FBC61, properties = 0x1A, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has read
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100574030, UUID = ADC3023D-BFD2-43FD-86F6-7AE05A619092, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100574090, UUID = A28B6BE1-2FA4-42F8-AEB2-B15A1DBD837A, properties = 0xA, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100574340, UUID = 7BE94A55-8D91-4592-BC0F-EA3664CCD3A9, properties = 0xA, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005703d0, UUID = 9C12A3DB-9CE8-4865-A217-D394B3BC9311, properties = 0xA, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005743a0, UUID = 16438C66-E95A-4C6F-8117-A6B745BD86FC, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100574400, UUID = 4656D3AC-C2DF-4096-96E7-713580B69CCD, properties = 0x1A, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has read
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100574460, UUID = 76B3DB1F-44C4-46CC-A7B5-E9CE7DFBEF50, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005746a0, UUID = 98924A39-6559-40A8-B302-3C8E40DBF834, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10045f4a0, UUID = 0188BF66-463A-405D-91FD-0B8940B92254, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10045f500, UUID = 2BDCAEBE-8746-45DF-A841-96B840980FB7, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10045f560, UUID = 2BDCAEBE-8746-45DF-A841-96B840980FB8, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x10045f600, UUID = 30E69638-3752-4FEB-A3AA-3226BCD05ACE, properties = 0x1A, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
... has notify
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100574700, UUID = F44A04D5-E0C6-4AD7-85D5-87D5AA33C9C6, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005744c0, UUID = E129F344-FC51-4A4A-8C97-08D4326030C6, properties = 0x4, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575070, UUID = 8B789F9B-2963-4307-88CE-26D042933800, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100574560, UUID = 4048127C-9DE7-4B8C-968E-8C6995C23800, properties = 0x4, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005745e0, UUID = 6001A31E-EF5E-4F27-A07C-31B9EE328286, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005704a0, UUID = 82E7D06B-65DA-4D78-99CB-BAF9635D8E6F, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100570530, UUID = E24FAC83-B5A8-4B9B-8FDA-803FFFB0C21C, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005707a0, UUID = D28617FE-0AD5-40C5-A04A-BC89051FF755, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100570890, UUID = 5F35C43D-E0F4-4DA9-87E6-9719982CD25E, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100570590, UUID = 353ECC73-4D2C-421B-AC1C-8DCB35CD4477, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005750d0, UUID = 6D5758A1-D4AF-4B32-B95E-1E6992454F4F, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575130, UUID = DCBE7A3E-A742-4527-AEB5-CD8DEE63167F, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100570640, UUID = 68BFA64E-3209-4172-B117-F7EAFCE17414, properties = 0x1A, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100570710, UUID = BBA1C7F1-B445-4657-90C3-8DBD97361A0C, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575190, UUID = 42E940EF-98C8-4CCD-A557-30425295AF89, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005751f0, UUID = 535442F7-0FF7-4FEC-9780-742F3EB00EDA, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575270, UUID = 1454E9D6-F658-4190-8589-22AA9E3021EB, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575370, UUID = E5892EBE-97D0-4F97-8F8E-CB85D16A4CC1, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005753d0, UUID = 60415E72-C345-417A-BB2B-BBBA95B2C9A3, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575430, UUID = 9215A295-B813-483F-9F85-B700D0B7BC75, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005754b0, UUID = 6E557876-CCC4-40E0-8C2D-651542C5AD3D, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575530, UUID = 50632720-4C0F-4BC4-960A-2404BDFDFBCA, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005755b0, UUID = 58BBCCC5-5A57-4E00-98D5-18C6A0408DFD, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x1005752f0, UUID = D01AB591-D282-4EF5-B83B-538E0BF32D85, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575700, UUID = BC6829C4-B750-48E6-B6F4-48EC866A1EFB, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575780, UUID = 51939BB6-A635-4B1E-903B-76CD9DFF3FAC, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575800, UUID = 786FF607-774D-49D6-80A5-A17E08823D91, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575880, UUID = D5D0AFFB-35B8-4FDC-A50B-F777C90293B8, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575900, UUID = 6EFAB52E-3002-4764-9430-016CEF4DFC87, properties = 0x4, value = (null), notifying = NO>
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575990, UUID = 34DFC7CB-5252-430B-BA6D-DF2FE87914E7, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has notify
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575a10, UUID = EBEE6F69-70B6-4BB9-B13B-9BA84953C233, properties = 0x1E, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
... has notify
... has read
<CBCharacteristic: 0x100575ab0, UUID = 62DCC92F-59C2-4228-9A11-C85F18773530, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>
... has write
```

But there's no dictionary available to get deeper information about the characteristic structure.
The hearing device is an Amplifon ampli-connect B 5 VS.

Again, how does one find the Bluetooth schema for a hearing or glucose tester device?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/asha  ?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, over the last couple of years, the bluetooth.com has become much more difficult to search. They've done away with a lot of the viewers, and you have to read PDFs. But the data is still there.

For hearing aids that support [LE Audio](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/le-audio/), see the [Volume Control Profile and Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/le-audio/). For the actual characteristic values, see the [16-bit UUID Numbers Document](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/). For example, the Volume Control service is 0x1844 and the Volume State characteristic is 0x2B7D. See the docs for details (it's not that complicated, but it's not obvious, either).

Many hearing aids do not use LE Audio, however. The first I believe were released in 2014 or so. Many use HFP and/or A2DP, which Core Bluetooth provides no access to. There is no supported way to change the volume in that case. (You can play games with a hidden MPVolumeView and programmatically find the slider and move it around, and I've done that for some products, but I really don't recommend it. It's incredibly fragile and unsupported.) HFP is generally used for phone calls, and is designed for voice. A2DP provides much higher-quality audio, generally for music. Devices that support either will show up in the iPhone's control panel automatically in most cases (depending on how the AVAudioSession is configured).

The device you've shown here has a bunch of 128-bit UUIDs, which strongly suggests a custom protocol, probably intended for use by an audiologist with manufacturer-provided software. Proprietary BLE protocols are very common in the earbud space (which is where I work), and from what I know of hearing aids, I expect they're very common there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this interesting info.

Comment: Further investigation shows me for the device mentioned, the communication is based on Apples MFI (made for iPhone) program. That's obviously an extension to the Audio LE protocol. Unfortunately the protocol is not open for all but the manufacturer of the device. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not aware of any LE Audio support specific to the the MFi program (I develop MFi devices). LE Audio is its own thing, managed by the Bluetooth SIG. I've heard something about an Apple-specific "LEA" protocol over Bluetooth (working with Cochlear), but I assume it's the predecessor of the SIG's LE Audio. But MFi doesn't have much to do with volume control. You get access to the iAP2 protocol, but that's serial link that you generally run proprietary protocols over (very similar to SPP). Changing volume is generally over HFP or A2DP, which MFi does not allow you to access.

Comment: As a rule, there is no supported way for an app to change the system volume. That's on purpose. And there's no generally supported way to change a Bluetooth device's volume through iOS (which is related to the system volume, but somewhat distinct). If you control the device firmware, you can create proprietary solutions to that over BLE or iAP2, but it won't be a solution for arbitrary devices. If you have a specific device you want to control, you'd need to discuss with its manufacturer to see if they have a proprietary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth.com no longer provides the XML viewer in their website. You need to download the profile as a PDF file.

eg:

[image]
for CGMP - https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=310501
for CGMS - https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=310502

basically, just go to https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/ and click on the 1.0.1 number for instance.

is this what you're looking for? The Specs / Profile?

Comment: Yes, but what about hearing aid devices? I can't find it within the list. In iOS for instance Apple doesn't know the hearing device which I connect and I can still control its volume or the programs via control panel. (without the control app by the manufacturer of the device) So there must be a specification exists for hearing aids too out there.

Comment: @frameworker google seems to indicate that it is just using the Bluetooth handsfree profile.

Comment: This is wha google says for android -- https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/asha

Comment: I saw the android asha doc. But I'm working with iOS. The problem is: I can scan many charcteristics but I don't know what's behind. Can it be, that all hearing aid's are based on https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/le-audio/?
But how can I decide which UUID mentioned above stands for? For instance: In the android doc there's an 0xfdf0 service. But look in the example output, there's no such service. But I can connect an iphone with that hearing device and I can control it: The channel, the volume. And I want to understand how can I make the same. And I didn't for now.

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/ try the Headset or handsfree profile. https://www.unitron.com/content/unitron/lk/en/professional/support/bluetooth/general/which-bluetooth-profiles-are-supported-with-the-bluetooth-hearing-aids.html

Comment: Nop, cannot discover characteristics for 0x1108 (headset), 0x111E or 0x111F. Must be another GATT specification or IOS recognize the device via UIKit Accessibility?

Comment: 0xfdf0 is Google's assigned number. It means it's Google proprietary. 0x1108 (HSP), 0x111e and 0x111f (both part of HFP) are classic profiles, not LE Services. To look up the numbers, see the Assigned Values doc: https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf (The fact that the Bluetooth committee hosts this on windows.net is one of the great weirdnesses of the bluetooth.com site…)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working myself to control volume (and many others features) of my Hearing Aid (Cochlear Nucleus) for nodejs and cordova/capacitor support.

The volume control you're looking is at Service:

```
7D74F4BD-C74A-4431-862C-CCE884371592
```

with Characteristic

```
4603580D-3C15-4FEC-93BE-B86B243ADA64
```

From there, you can write `0x00` (lowest volume) to `0xFF`(highest volume).

I hope that helps. I'm also having trouble finding specifications, I only found this one by doing reverse engineer.

Answer (score 0):

I show the virtual same exchanges of UUIDs for a hearing aid that I analyzed at Bluetooth [physical layer](https://learn.adafruit.com/ble-sniffer-with-nrf52840) using AdaFruit Bluetooth [UF2](https://www.adafruit.com/product/5199) USB fob and [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) packet analyzer.

And I can see that you are trying to pair a hearing aid to Linux.  And I successfully did it.

At [Debian 12](https://www.debian.org/download) (bookworm) using [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org) v5.66, pipewire v0.3.65, AND this Debian APT package of `pipewire-pulse` v0.3.65, this audio streaming now works by executing the following:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
```

and executing the following bluetoothctl commands at each `[bluetooth]#`  prompt:

```
devices 
select  
list    
show    
power on
scan bredr 
# press appropriate button on hearing aid (HA) to start BT pairing
# while scanning, note the MAC address of this HA device
# replace all xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx with this HA MAC address
pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

and you should get the following output:

```
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Paired: yes
Pairing successful
```

then you can exit the `bluetoothctl`

```
[bluetooth]# exit
$
```

Comment: @DarkLordCoder, I know you are monitoring this topic.